# moto not mocking ec2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mocking, boto, moto

I'm trying to test some python code that uses boto. I'd rather not try and do an integration test against AWS, so I am trying to mock it out with moto, and it's not behaving as I'd expect.

Here's the test code:

```
import io
import boto3

from moto import mock_ec2
from unittest.mock import patch
from argparse import Namespace
from awswl import commands


@mock_ec2
@patch('awswl.externalip.get_external_ip', return_value='192.0.2.1')
def test_list_command_lists_ipv4_and_ipv6_cidrs(exip_method):
    # Given
    options = Namespace()
    options.sgid = "sg-123456"

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    sg = ec2.create_security_group(
        Description='Security Group for SSH Whitelisting',
        GroupName='SSH Whitelist'
    )
    print("Created security group: {0}".format(sg.GroupId))
```

And the error:

```
Testing started at 16:46 ...
/path/.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/bin/python "/path/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/173.4301.16/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py" --target test_commands.py::test_list_command_lists_ipv4_and_ipv6_cidrs
Launching py.test with arguments test_commands.py::test_list_command_lists_ipv4_and_ipv6_cidrs in /path/awswl/tests

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /path/awswl, inifile:
collected 1 item
test_commands.py F
tests/test_commands.py:22 (test_list_command_lists_ipv4_and_ipv6_cidrs)
exip_method = <MagicMock name='get_external_ip' id='4547595848'>

    @mock_ec2
    @patch('awswl.externalip.get_external_ip', return_value='192.0.2.1')
    def test_list_command_lists_ipv4_and_ipv6_cidrs(exip_method):
        # Given
        options = Namespace()
        options.sgid = "sg-123456"

>       ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

test_commands.py:30: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py:92: in resource
    return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/session.py:389: in resource
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/session.py:263: in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/session.py:861: in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py:76: in create_client
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py:285: in _get_client_args
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/args.py:45: in get_client_args
    endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/args.py:111: in compute_client_args
    service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py:358: in resolve
    service_name, region_name)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/regions.py:122: in construct_endpoint
    partition, service_name, region_name)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <botocore.regions.EndpointResolver object at 0x10f1a3908>
partition = OrderedDict([('defaults', OrderedDict([('hostname', '{service}.{region}.{dnsSuffix}'), ('protocols', ['https']), ('sig...1', OrderedDict()), ('us-east-2', OrderedDict()), ('us-west-1', OrderedDict()), ('us-west-2', OrderedDict())]))]))]))])
service_name = 'ec2', region_name = None

    def _endpoint_for_partition(self, partition, service_name, region_name):
        # Get the service from the partition, or an empty template.
        service_data = partition['services'].get(
            service_name, DEFAULT_SERVICE_DATA)
        # Use the partition endpoint if no region is supplied.
        if region_name is None:
            if 'partitionEndpoint' in service_data:
                region_name = service_data['partitionEndpoint']
            else:
>               raise NoRegionError()
E               botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/regions.py:135: NoRegionError
                                                       [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________ test_list_command_lists_ipv4_and_ipv6_cidrs __________________

exip_method = <MagicMock name='get_external_ip' id='4547595848'>

    @mock_ec2
    @patch('awswl.externalip.get_external_ip', return_value='192.0.2.1')
    def test_list_command_lists_ipv4_and_ipv6_cidrs(exip_method):
        # Given
        options = Namespace()
        options.sgid = "sg-123456"

>       ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

test_commands.py:30: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py:92: in resource
    return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/session.py:389: in resource
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/session.py:263: in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/session.py:861: in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py:76: in create_client
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py:285: in _get_client_args
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/args.py:45: in get_client_args
    endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/args.py:111: in compute_client_args
    service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py:358: in resolve
    service_name, region_name)
../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/regions.py:122: in construct_endpoint
    partition, service_name, region_name)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <botocore.regions.EndpointResolver object at 0x10f1a3908>
partition = OrderedDict([('defaults', OrderedDict([('hostname', '{service}.{region}.{dnsSuffix}'), ('protocols', ['https']), ('sig...1', OrderedDict()), ('us-east-2', OrderedDict()), ('us-west-1', OrderedDict()), ('us-west-2', OrderedDict())]))]))]))])
service_name = 'ec2', region_name = None

    def _endpoint_for_partition(self, partition, service_name, region_name):
        # Get the service from the partition, or an empty template.
        service_data = partition['services'].get(
            service_name, DEFAULT_SERVICE_DATA)
        # Use the partition endpoint if no region is supplied.
        if region_name is None:
            if 'partitionEndpoint' in service_data:
                region_name = service_data['partitionEndpoint']
            else:
>               raise NoRegionError()
E               botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

../../../../../.virtualenvs/awswl-Ir8BWU8l/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/regions.py:135: NoRegionError
=========================== 1 failed in 1.80 seconds ===========================
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It looks like it's invoking boto, not mocking it out with Moto, and I'm getting a NoRegionError because there's no region/profile specified.

What am I doing wrong? I assume it's me, but I haven't figured out how. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the problem as the test output points out might be related to not specifying any region when creating the resource with boto3.
From your test output:

`botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.`

Checking also [moto's tests](https://github.com/spulec/moto/search?l=Python&p=1&q=boto3.resource%28%27ec2%27&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93), looks like the region is always specified there as well.

Simply initialising the resource with an example region should fix your problem:

```
boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
```

Comment: You're right -- I had mistakenly assumed: (a) Moto didn't need a region. (b) the fact that the code throwing the exception was Boto meant that Moto mocking somehow wasn't working. However, as soon as I set os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'], the mocking starts working as expected.

Comment: The way moto mocking integrates is actually fairly deep in the boto stack -- it's more like having mock service (although the http part is mocked, not just the remote end).